# Calculation with many fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 4 fields for me to do the calculation, they should add up together and give me the total sum. However, there are some problems with fields when it is empty.

The code and script is below:

```
<tr id="row">
  <td>No. of Dependant(s)</td>
  <td><input type="text" id="Dep-main" value="0"></td>
  <td><input type="text" id="Dep-joint1" value="0"></td>
  <td><input type="text" id="Dep-joint2" value="0"></td>
  <td><input type="text" id="Dep-joint3" value="0"></td>
  <td><input type="text" id="Total-dep" readonly></td>
</tr>
```

The script:

```
   <script>

                var main = document.getElementById("Dep-main");
                var joint1 = document.getElementById("Dep-joint1");
                var joint2 = document.getElementById("Dep-joint2");
                var joint3 = document.getElementById("Dep-joint3");
                var total = document.getElementById("Total-dep");
                1
                var inputs = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("td > input"));

                inputs.forEach(function (input) {

                    input.addEventListener("blur", function () {
                        // Always supply the second argument to parseInt() (the radix) so you
                        // dont' get non-base 10 answers.

                        if (main.value.length === 0) {

                            total.value = parseFloat(joint1.value) + parseFloat(joint2.value) + parseFloat(joint3.value);
                        } else if (joint1.value.length === 0) {

                            total.value = parseFloat(main.value) + parseFloat(joint2.value) + parseFloat(joint3.value);

                        } else if (joint2.value.length === 0) {

                            total.value = parseFloat(main.value) + parseFloat(joint1.value) + parseFloat(joint3.value);

                        } else if (joint3.value.length === 0) {

                            total.value = parseFloat(main.value) + parseFloat(joint1.value) + parseFloat(joint2.value);

                        }else{

                        total.value = parseFloat(main.value) + parseFloat(joint1.value) + parseFloat(joint2.value) + parseFloat(joint3.value);

                    }



                    });

                });
</script>
```

However, if there is 2 or more fields are empty, the Total field will appear NaN. Is there any way for me to keep the field as empty and get the total number?

Comment: Why is there a php tag?

Comment: @Daniel Gone! :-)

Comment: When should it be summed ?

Comment: What is the random `1` doing in there?

Comment: There are four fields, main + joint1 + joint2 +joint3 = total. However, the total will appear NaN if 2 or more fields did not have value.

Comment: @Weedoze it should be summed up on document change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My original idea was flawed in that it would not update the final value if a field was subsequently cleared of a value. Using an object to maintain the values for any element that has received the `blur` event and then performing a sum calculation of the values seems to work OK.

```
var total = {};
/* returns numeric value of field or zero if empty etc */
function fieldvalue(id){
    var field=document.getElementById( id );
    return field.value!='' && field.value.length > 0 && !isNaN( parseFloat( field.value ) ) ? parseFloat( field.value ) : 0;
}

var col=document.querySelectorAll('tr#row > td > input:not([readonly])');
if( col ){
    for( var n in col )if( col[ n ].nodeType==1 ){
        col[n].addEventListener('blur',function(event){
            total[ this.id ]=fieldvalue( this.id );
            document.getElementById('Total-dep').value=Object.values(total).reduce(function(a,b){return a+b;});
        }.bind( col[n] ),false);
    }
}
```

or, more akin to the original code using `Array.prototype.slice`

```
/*
    The aim here is to select all input elements that are not marked
    as "readonly" as it is these that will be used for the calculations
    whilst the "readonly" field is updated programmatically only.
*/
var col=document.querySelectorAll('tr#row > td > input:not([readonly])');

/*
     Convert array-like object into a true array in order that we can use
     Array.forEach() method which does not work for all browsers when dealing
     with HTMLCollections - such as a nodelist
*/
var inputs = Array.prototype.slice.call( col );
inputs.forEach(function(e){
    /*
        Assign the `onblur` event handler to each of the input elements
        - the callback to the event handler will update the `total` object
        which is then later processed to calculate the sum of values stored.
    */
    e.addEventListener('blur',function(event){
        /*
            Update the total object with field value
        */
        total[ this.id ]=fieldvalue( this.id );
        /*
            Update the "readonly" field with calculated sum of values
        */
        document.getElementById('Total-dep').value=Object.values( total ).reduce(function(a,b){return a+b;});
    }.bind( e ),false);
});
```

Perhaps worth noting is the use of `Object.values(obj)` - it is not supported by all browsers ( IE, Opera & Safari for instance ) but there are `polyfills` available [here](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-values-entries/blob/master/polyfill.js) and [here](https://github.com/es-shims/Object.values/blob/master/polyfill.js)

And, I just wrote this - not stringently tested btw

```
if( typeof( Object.values )!='function' ){
    Object.prototype.values=function(obj){
        var tmp=[];
        var keys=Array.prototype.slice.call( Object.keys( obj ) );
        keys.forEach(function( item ){
            tmp.push( obj[item] )
        });
        return tmp;
    };
}
```

Comment: what is the fieldvalue(id)? is it total? And, for the field.value , do I need to make changes to it?

Comment: Is it just replace your script with mine or just replace it with my 'inputs.forEach(function (input)'

Comment: The final piece of code I posted should suffice - copy and use "as is"

Answer (score 0):

i would loop the fields, and if contains something add it.

```
total.value = 0;
if (main.value.length === 0) {
    total.value += parseFloat(main.value);
}
if (join1.value.length === 0) {
    total.value += parseFloat(join1.value);
}
if (join2.value.length === 0) {
    total.value += parseFloat(join2.value);
}
if (join3.value.length === 0) {
    total.value += parseFloat(join3.value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking null value in **if else** statement that why you are getting the error so you need to check separately

Just do like this

```
var total=0;

if (main.value.length != 0) {
    total = total+parseFloat(main.value);
}
if (joint1.value.length != 0) {
    total = total+parseFloat(joint1.value);
}
if (joint2.value.length != 0) {
    total = total+parseFloat(joint2.value);
}
if (joint3.value.length != 0) {
    total = total+parseFloat(joint3.value);
}
total.value = total
```

It will help you to solve our issue.

Answer (score 0):

I did not get what you are really after. However, I believe using such checks will lead you to the solution:

```
var x = $("#someFloatExpectedInput").val();
var y = $("#someIntExpectedInput").val();

if (!isNaN(parseFloat(x))) {
    //
}

if (!isNaN(parseInt(y))) {
    //
}
```